# Can websites that is embedded in an iframe, reads parent website cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a html page where there is an iframe added. Inside that iframe i have loaded another html page. Both are different domains. Now can the iframe website read the cookies of its parent website? If not then how can i make the iframe wesbite read its parent website cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Of course not, a cookie is bound to a domain. Imagine if advertisers could retrieve the session cookie in every page their ads are embedded in.

The parent page has to provide the cookie of his own accord to an `iframe`, (ideally with [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)) but an `iframe` is not able to retrieve the parent cookie on its own.